# Extend Emacs to edit encrypted text files

Tags: security, emacs, openssl, elisp

I am trying to add special handling to emacs to handle Triple-DES encrypted files (any file with extension .des3 is assumed to be a valid encrypted text file).

My approach is to append to format-alist, like so:

```
(setq format-alist 
      (cons (list 'des3 "Triple-DES encrypted files"
            ".*\.des3" "show" "" t nil)
          format-alist))
```

Where *show* is the following command-line script (verified working from the command line):

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl des3 -d -in $1
```

Expected:
When opening a *.des3* file I will be prompted for a password (by show) and then see the cleartext context in the emacs buffer. [note: I will also add save/encrypt later, but for now I want to get open working]

Actual:
When opening a *.des3* file, I do not get a prompt from *show*, or any indication that show has been called, and the buffer contains the encrypted file contents.

Comment: Have you ever finished writing your code to use Emacs with OpenSSL?

Comment: No, it slid pretty far down my to-do list. But I will post anything relevant when I get back to finish it.

Comment: The regexp `".*\.des3"` matches the same strings as `".des3"`, i.e. any string with `des3` inside and at least one char before that.  You probably mean to use `"\\.des3\\'"`. which only matches name that end in `.des3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format-alist` is applied to the file *contents*, not its name.  I think you want `file-name-handler-alist` instead.  See [Making Certain File Names "Magic"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Magic-File-Names) in the Emacs manual for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [ps-ccrypt.el](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/ps-ccrypt.el) for inspiration. It's a package that integrates with [ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/). It does what your want for .cpt files.

Comment: Thanks, this example is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this crypt++.el with the changes mentioned in :

https://github.com/tphan88/EmacsOpenSSLCrypt

You may added your own encryption/decryption command if you know how to determine the "file magic" number.

THe EmacsOpenSSLCrypt hard coded some string to check for decrypting.